How to make Halftones Render Composite in Blender?
Does everybody know how to do only halftone composites? I want a dotted style below this picture, and I don't want anything with the material mesh.


Please add pictures or videos as an example.

No idea how to do that with Compositor nodes, but you can do that with shader nodes.
The idea would be to first pixelate the image by rounding UV coordinates:

Here I just repeat the same for U and V(or should I say X and Y?..):

So rounding is a bit funny in Blender for some reason and you can only round to integers so that's why all the trouble with first multiplying and then dividing the coordinates by some number while rounding in between. The add node just adds an offset so the image edge doesn't end up in the middle of a pixel.
OK, so pixelated:

Then I need voronoi texture with 0 randomization so I have a radial  gradient for every single pixel. The math is just to figure out the correct scale for specific amount of pixels and I also have a math power node at the end to control the brightness/dot size:

Alone the voronoi texture should look like that:

Just tiny radial gradiants:

And now I need to mix those gradiants with the image pixel values with math nodes in Greater Than mode:

The problem is - I want to do that for each channel and also offset each channel as well, so let's do that 3 times:




Oh, yeah, that should probably be CMYK :D, not RGB. :D :D :D Anyway, the idea is the same. And by "I don't want anything with the material mesh." you did probably mean you don't want a MATERIAL NODES solution which I did not understand and ignored... Anyway, I don't think it's going to be easy in Compositor nodes. I guess you could prerender the radial gradient and do the same...
